# variable is not passed by reference

Tags: c++

I have compile and run my program correctly but it seems that the variable sum is not passed by reference and it still got 0.  Any help here is the code.

```
#include "VendingMachine.h"

int VendingMachine::MakeSelection(int ItemPrice[], int NumItems[],int &sum){

    int total_cost = 0;

    cout << "Enter your choice: ";
    cin >> choice;

    if(choice >= 1 && choice <= 9){
        while (choice != 0){
            NumItems[(choice-1) % 10]--;
            total_cost += ItemPrice[(choice-1)%10];
            choice/=10;

        }
    }
        sum = total_cost;
        return sum;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include "VendingMachine.h"

int main()
{
    int Denominations = 5;

    int Coins[] = {100, 50, 20, 10, 5};
    int NumCoins[] = {10, 10, 10, 10, 10}; //assume we have 10 coins of each denomination

    const int Items = 9;
    int sum, deposit;

    int ItemPrice[ ] = { 75, 120, 120, 100, 150, 95, 110, 50, 120 }; //price in cents
    int  NumItems[ ] = { 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10 }; 

    VendingMachine caller;

    caller.ShowMenu();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter your money: ";
    cin >> deposit;

    caller.MakeSelection(ItemPrice,NumItems,sum);
    cout <<"The total cost is " << sum << endl;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Vending.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int total_cost;
int Coins[5];
int NumCoins[5];
int ItemPrice[9];
int NumItems[9];

class VendingMachine{
public:
    int MakeSelection(int ItemPrice[], int NumItems[],int &sum);
    void ReturnChange(int& input,int& sum, int Coins[],int NumCoins[]);
    void ShowMenu();
    void DisplayErrorMessage(int error);
    void PrintConfidentialInformation(int Denominations, int Items, int Coins[], int NumCoins[], int ItemPrice[] , int NumItems[]);
private:
    int choice;
    string Password;
    int deposit2;
};
```

The total cost should return a value of sum in the MakeSelection cpp but still it returns a 0..??

Comment: `sum` isn't used. There's a warning for that.

Comment: The function doesn't have a return value, so you're getting undefined behavior.

Comment: You should enable some flags in your compiler ...

Comment: Hey guys apologies for the incomplete of my above code I've just edited it adding two lines of code which utilized the variable sum and this is where I don't understand why it returns 0...Any help..!!

Comment: What is the point of `choice/=10;` and `%10` when choice cannot be more than 9 at that point?

Comment: Why are you returning `sum` and passing it by reference in method `MakeSelection`?  In general, you either return the value or modify a parameter, not both.

Answer (score 1):

MakeSelection does not use variable sum at all.

Answer (score 0):

You never actually use sum, hence the value is 0

Answer (score 0):

Your `sum` variable isn't being used and your `MakeSelection` call isn't returning any value.